# Curl does not recognise Json array parameter (Windows 10)

Tags: arrays, json, api, curl, post

I am trying to make an HTTPS post call to a third party company's API using the following curl command from within the Windows 10 CMD.

```
curl -u "username:x" -X POST -k -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data-urlencode -d 'envelope_documents=[{"document_title":"Test Contract","document_template_fingerprint":"template_id","document_merge_fields":[{"field_id":16012217,"field_value":"Dimitrios Efthymiou"},{"field_id":16012218,"field_value":"Fulham Palace Road"}]}]' -d 'envelope_parties=[{"party_id":2632177,"party_name":"Party","party_email":"hello@example.org","party_message":"Please sign this!"}]' -d "envelope_title=Test Contract" https://api.signable.co.uk/v1/envelopes
```

After running I get the following error:

> The party information is missing. To be able to create a new envelope, you must provide a JSON array of signing parties.

We have already tried the following: 

  1. Removing the "-k" parameter,

  2. Removing "data-urlencode",

No luck. When the third party company runs this command it works properly but, they cannot help us any further.

We need to run this in windows. Please help!

Thanks.